# Visual Studio NUnit adapter only run 10K tests at a time

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, nunit

I am using VS 2017 with NUnit 3.10.  I have a solution that has ~50K unit tests.  The registered test time in the explorer window is 5-10 minutes (most of the tests take less than a millisecond).  However, when running, it actually takes much longer than that.  Every 10,000 tests, there is a long pause (several minutes) where seemingly nothing happens.  Then the next 10K picks up, and then another pause, and so on and so forth.

- It doesn't seem to matter if I run the tests in parallel or in serial.  The pause between 10K groups is the same.
- I can't find anything in NUnit's or Visual Studio's dcoumentation around a 10K limit or threshold regarding test runs.
- A similar solution that runs xUnit tests (with again around 50K tests) instead of NUnit does not have this issue with long pauses between sets of 10K

Here is an example of the test output, running a subset of my tests (~26K of them)

```
[10/5/2018 10:19:05 AM Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[10/5/2018 10:19:12 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution started
[10/5/2018 10:19:13 AM Informational] Running selected tests in C:\Users\kspeer\Documents\GitHub\CreatureGen\CreatureGen.Tests.Unit\bin\Debug\CreatureGen.Tests.Unit.dll
[10/5/2018 10:19:27 AM Informational] NUnit3TestExecutor converted 25908 of 25908 NUnit test cases
[10/5/2018 10:26:35 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution complete
[10/5/2018 10:26:41 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution started
[10/5/2018 10:26:41 AM Informational] Running selected tests in C:\Users\kspeer\Documents\GitHub\CreatureGen\CreatureGen.Tests.Unit\bin\Debug\CreatureGen.Tests.Unit.dll
[10/5/2018 10:26:56 AM Informational] NUnit3TestExecutor converted 25908 of 25908 NUnit test cases
[10/5/2018 10:34:14 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution complete
[10/5/2018 10:34:19 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution started
[10/5/2018 10:34:19 AM Informational] Running selected tests in C:\Users\kspeer\Documents\GitHub\CreatureGen\CreatureGen.Tests.Unit\bin\Debug\CreatureGen.Tests.Unit.dll
[10/5/2018 10:34:33 AM Informational] NUnit3TestExecutor converted 25908 of 25908 NUnit test cases
[10/5/2018 10:38:58 AM Informational] Running selected tests in C:\Users\kspeer\Documents\GitHub\CreatureGen\CreatureGen.Tests.Integration.IoC\bin\Debug\CreatureGen.Tests.Integration.IoC.dll
[10/5/2018 10:38:58 AM Informational] NUnit3TestExecutor converted 26 of 26 NUnit test cases
[10/5/2018 10:38:59 AM Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution complete
[10/5/2018 10:38:59 AM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 25932 run (0:19:54.0766142) ==========
```

The registered run in the test explorer is only 37 seconds, as opposed to the 21 minutes in the logs.

[image: Test Count and Duration in Explorer]

Why does this happen?  Is there anything I can configure or do to improve this?

UPDATE 1: I ran the same tests using the NUnit console runner, and there was no pause.

[image: NUnit Console Runner]

UPDATE 2: More interestingly, I ran the tests in Visual Studio 2017 Community edition, and did not see the pause.  Where I am seeing the pause is only in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition.

UPDATE 3: If you "Run All", there is no gap.  If you run a particular project, the gap occurs.

Comment: I swear to you that we did not put in a long pause every 10000 tests. :-)

I suggest running under nunit3-console as a way of localizing the problem to the test adapter versus the NUnit framework itself.

Comment: Note that as the tests run, VS receives the results for them one at a time. So in addition to the framework and adapter, VS is a suspect too!

Comment: Thanks @Charlie.  I added the results of a console run to the question.  Now the likely culprit is Visual Studio 2017